# COPY ... FROM LOCAL does not output error on console

Tags: mysql, vertica

`COPY .. FROM LOCAL` does not output error on console.
For example:

```
create table test (col1 INT);
```

and I have a file (`abc.data`) containing data to insert to the table `test` as below

```
1237232632624232
111
222
```

I used the command as below to insert data into table

```
COPY test from local 'abc.data';
```

I expect it outputs error (overflow) on console. However, it does not. I workarounded by using `EXCEPTIONS` to output the error to file.

How do you know the way to output the error on console? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Vertica doesn't fail `COPY` command on every bad row. Instead, It writes the errors and the bad rows to files in a directory called `CopyErrorLogs` located under Vertica's catalog path.

You can choose another location for those error files using `EXCEPTIONS` and `REJECTED DATA` options (like you did).

Or, which may be more convenient, write the errors and bad data into a table:

`COPY test from local 'abc.data' REJECTED DATA as TABLE test_rejected;`

Then, you can analyze `test_rejected` with sql

```
dbadmin=> \x
Expanded display is on.
dbadmin=> select * from test_rejected limit 1;
-[ RECORD 1 ]---+------------------------------------------------------------------
file_name       | abc.data
row_number      | 1
rejected_data   | 1237232632624232123243214
rejected_reason | int8 out of range '1237232632624232123243214' for column 1 (col1)
```

If you wish to fail `COPY` command on every bad row use `ABORT ON ERROR`. e.g:

```
dbadmin=> COPY test from local 'abc.data' ABORT ON ERROR;
ERROR 2035:  COPY: Input record 1 has been rejected (int8 out of range '1237232632624232123243214' for column 1 (col1))
```

Comment: Can i get sqlstate in this case?

Comment: There is not sqlstate because it doesn't count as failure

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REJECTMAX 1` if you want the copy command to fail with an error message when a row is rejected (although it won't be specific).
Then you can investigate further using the exceptions and rejected data files or rejected data table.

Further reading in the documentation on load errors:
https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BulkLoadCOPY/CapturingLoadExceptionsAndRejections.htm

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
load data infile 'abc.data' into table test fields terminated by ',';
```

Comment: Thanks, but i would like to use `copy` only

Comment: @hhy `copy` seems to be a `PostgreSQL` syntax, not mysql, and your tag is `mysql`.

Comment: What are you using to execute the COPY command? VSQL? vertica-python? DbVisualizer?

Comment: I used vertica console (Vertica Analytic Database v9.1.1-4)

Comment: @hhy Vertica Console is not a thing. Do you mean Vertica Management Console or vsql?

Comment: I use vsql (version v9.1.1-4)